# Can't save kafka offset in zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-kafka, centos7, hortonworks-data-platform

I've installed Zookeeper and Kafka from Ambari, on CentoS 7.

Ambari version: 2.1.2.1
Zookeeper version: 3.4.6.2.3
Kafka version: 0.8.2.2.3
Java Kafka client:kafka_2.10, 0.8.2.2

I'm trying to save the Kafka offset, using the following code:

```
SimpleConsumer simpleConsumer = new SimpleConsumer(host, port, soTimeout, bufferSize, clientId);
TopicAndPartition topicAndPartition = new TopicAndPartition(topicName, partitionId);
Map<TopicAndPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> requestInfo = new HashMap<>();
requestInfo.put(topicAndPartition, new OffsetAndMetadata(readOffset, "", ErrorMapping.NoError()));
OffsetCommitRequest offsetCommitRequest = new OffsetCommitRequest(groupName, requestInfo, correlationId, clientName, (short)0);
simpleConsumer.commitOffsets(offsetCommitRequest);
simpleConsumer.close();
```

But when I run this, I get the following error in my client:

```
java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
```

Also in the Kafka logs I have the following error:

```
[2015-11-24 15:38:53,566] ERROR Closing socket for /192.168.186.1 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:498)
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getLong(HeapByteBuffer.java:406)
    at kafka.api.OffsetCommitRequest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(OffsetCommitRequest.scala:73)
    at kafka.api.OffsetCommitRequest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(OffsetCommitRequest.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.api.OffsetCommitRequest$$anonfun$1.apply(OffsetCommitRequest.scala:68)
    at kafka.api.OffsetCommitRequest$$anonfun$1.apply(OffsetCommitRequest.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.api.OffsetCommitRequest$.readFrom(OffsetCommitRequest.scala:65)
    at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$9.apply(RequestKeys.scala:47)
    at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$9.apply(RequestKeys.scala:47)
    at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:55)
    at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:547)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:405)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Now I've also downloaded and installed the official Kafka 0.8.2.2 version from https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.8.2.2/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.tgz and it works ok; you can save the Kafka offset without any error.

Can anybody give me a some directions, why is the Ambari Kafka failing to save the offset?

P.S: I know that if versionId is 0 (in OffsetCommitRequest), than the offset is actually saved in Zookeeper.

Comment: Hi Buzzer. I have the same problem you have and can't find an answer on the web for it... Did you find a solution that you could share? Thanks!

Comment: This is an old question and possibly no longer relevant. However, it seems similar questions have been answered like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38582048/685760). Just adding this in case some one else stumbles across this question.