# java.nio.BufferUnderflowException while reading from kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running into BufferUnderflowException error while consuming events from kafka. I am able to read about 100k messages successfully and after that I hit this error.

I have come across few stackoverflow posts where this can happen when the server version and consumer version does not match as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564784/error-reading-field-topics-java-nio-bufferunderflowexception-in-kafka). But, my consumer and server versions match.

I would appreciate your thoughts on how to debug this.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'responses': Error reading field 'topic': java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(Schema.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:464)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:279)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:197)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:877)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:829)
    at com.howtoprogram.kafka.ConsumerTest.main(ConsumerTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Kafka server version

```
kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0
```

Kafka consumer version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Consumer jar

```
kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0.jar
```

Code

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class ConsumerTest {
  public static AtomicLong totalMessages = new AtomicLong(0);  
  static String bootstrapServers = "10.0.1.1:9092";
  static String consumerGroup = ConsumerTest.class.getSimpleName();
  static String topic = "events.topic";


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
    props.put("group.id", consumerGroup);
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");


    System.out.println("init kafka consumer kafka - 0.9.0.0" );
    try {
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));


        System.out.println("subscribed to kafka topic " + topic );

        while (true) {
          ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
          totalMessages.addAndGet(records.count());
          System.out.println("totalMessages = " + totalMessages.get());
          for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
          }
    }}
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("something went wrong");
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(System.out));
    }

  }

}
```

Not sure if it matters but, the producer is a spark job which is version 0.8.2 ..so, a bit older.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

-----update------

I was able to reproduce this with another producer I wrote. The producer is based on code using kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0.jar (same as consumer)

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class ProducerTest {
     static String topic = "events.topic";
    static String bootstrapServers = "10.0.1.1:9092";

    static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    Producer<String, String> producer = null;

    DummyObject event = new DummyObject();
    event.id = "somerandompsid";
    event.country_cd = "US";
    event.cont_id = "programId";
    event.language = "EN";
    event.category = "category";
    event.subcategory = "sub category";
    event.source_id  = "12234";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(event);

    try {
      producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
      System.out.println("kafka producer " + bootstrapServers + ",topic= " + topic);
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, json));
        counter.addAndGet(1);
//        System.out.println("Sent:" + json);
      }
      System.out.println("sent messages " + counter.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(System.out));
    } finally {
      producer.close();
    }

  }

}
```

-------another update-------

downgraded the consumer to use - kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.jar and changed it o use [kafka streams](https://github.com/kmiku7/kafka-0.8.2.1/blob/master/kafka-0.8.2.1-src/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Consumer.java) . Although I didn't hit the above bufferunderflow exception, the consumer gets stuck at times and does not read all the messages on kafka. I don't see any exception either. Below is the code,

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;
import kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata;

public class KafkaConsumerThread extends Thread {
    private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
    private final String topic;
    AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

    public KafkaConsumerThread(String topic) {
        consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(createConsumerConfig());
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", KafkaProperties.zkConnect);
        props.put("group.id", KafkaProperties.groupId);
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "4000");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");

        System.out.println("listening to zookeper " + KafkaProperties.zkConnect);

        return new ConsumerConfig(props);

    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("listening to topic " + topic);
        try {
            Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1));
            Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
            KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = consumerMap.get(topic).get(0);
            System.out.println("got the stream");
            ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
            System.out.println("iterating the stream");
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> next = it.next();
                String msg = new String(next.message());
                // System.out.println(msg);
                counter.incrementAndGet();
                System.out.println("Consumed = " + counter.get());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong ");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            KafkaConsumerThread consumerThread = new KafkaConsumerThread(KafkaProperties.topic);
            consumerThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong main loop ");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        for (;;) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posted on kafka-clients google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kafka-clients/mfK5Ra2vvV8

Comment: The same code with producer/consumer works fine on latest kafka server version - kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0.jar